# ¿Cómo escapar un caracter especial de una expresión regular en MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, regex

Quiero buscar la siguiente cadena `A$(` pero MySQL no reconoce `\(` como un caracter escapado. Desde Java utilizo `A$\\(` para escapar.

Tengo la siguiente expresión:

```
SELECT refaccion.id, 
       refaccion.codigoInterno, 
       refaccion.codigoProveedor, 
       refaccion.nombre, 
       refaccion.descripcion, 
       refaccion.stockMinimo, 
       refaccion.stockMaximo, 
       unidad.unidad, 
       importancia.importancia 
FROM refaccion 
INNER JOIN 
        importancia ON importancia.id = refaccion.importancia 
INNER JOIN 
        unidad ON unidad.id = refaccion.unidad 
WHERE 
        nombre REGEXP '.*A$\(|A$\(.*'  
    OR 
        codigoInterno REGEXP '.*A$\(|A$\(.*'  
    OR 
        codigoProveedor REGEXP '.*A$\(|A$\(.*'  
    OR 
        descripcion REGEXP '.*A$\(|A$\(.*'  
    OR 
        importancia.importancia REGEXP '.*A$\(|A$\(.*'  
    ORDER BY importancia.id ASC;
```

¿Cómo escapar este caracter?

Comment: Hola,  deberías escapar `$` si lo que quieres buscar es `A$(`

Comment: Ok, gracias eso no lo sabía.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es correcto escaparlo como `\\(`, pero el signo `$` también es un caracter especial para una expresión regular.

Quedaría:

```
nombre REGEXP 'A\\$\\('
```

O como string en Java:

```
consulta = "select * from tabla where nombre regexp 'A\\\\$\\\\('";
```

- Java interpreta cada doble barra, y luego MySQL interpreta cada doble barra.

  - Así está en tu código: `A\\\\$\\\\(`
  - Así lo ve Java: `A\\$\\(`
  - Así lo ve MySQL: `A\$\(`
  - Y el motor de regex lo ve como el literal 
    `A$(`

---

Los caracteres especiales en regex son:

```
\ ^ $ . | ? * + ( ) [ {
```

Más información en [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

Comment: ¿El doble ` \\ ` tiene que salir en MySQL ? Agregue desde java ` \\\\ ` y parece que me funciono sin escapar `\\$`.  Funciono así  `A$\\(`. Escape de todos modos por seguridad pero ¿a qué se debe que no me estaba dando error? Y otra cosa, los caracteres `[` y `{` se escapan pero sus contrapartes no se ocupan?

Comment: Es correcto, desde Java se necesitan 4 barras por cada una (Java interpreta cada doble barra, y luego MySQL interpreta cada doble barra). Cuando no se escapa el signo `$`, no te da un error, ya que es válido, porque `$` coincide con el final del string, pero jamás va a coincidir según tu intención... Y sí, un `]` o un `}` que no fueron abiertos son interpretados como literales.